# I currently have a problem where I'm trying to query a nested mongoose object in grapql but can't seem to figure it out

Tags: mongoose, nested, graphql, resolver

I am using mongoose and graphql on the backend and I am having some trouble returning a nested mongoose object in the graphql resolver. I am able to save the data to the database with a graphql mutation but when I try to return the data I get back null in the graphql playground.

If anyone is able to help this would be much appreciated.

[Mongoose schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hlmB.png)

[Graphql schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvTPC.png)

[Graphql mutation and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6eJ1.png)

If yo look at my mongoose schema you will see that I have username nested inside the customer object. I do not know how to get access to this in graphql, if anyone is able to provide me with the solution it would be of grat help. Thanks a million

Comment: Add the code as a live text (google "markdown code"), not as screenshots.

Comment: try `const newUser = await user.save();` (Google "async await")

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the example I have provided below. The following properties, customer, address, shippingAddress, social, payment, userFollowers, and userFollowing are all nested obects within my mongoose schema. The below example shows how I was able to access these nested objects using graphql. As you can see you have to use a custom type.

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'User',
fields: () => ({
id: { type: GraphQLID },
date: { type: GraphQLString },
customer: { type: CustomerType },
address: { type: AddressType },
shippingAddress: { type: ShippingAddressType },
social: { type: SocialType },
payment: { type: PaymentType },
userFollowers: { type: UserFollowersType },
userFollowing: { type: UserFollowingType },

```
})
```

});

This is the custom customer type. I had to do one of there for each nested property.

const CustomerType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Customer',
fields: () => ({
username: { type: GraphQLString },
email: { type: GraphQLString },
password: { type: GraphQLString },
gender: { type: GraphQLString },
dob: { type: GraphQLString },
bio: { type: GraphQLString }
})
});